# Aligning a stackview to the top of the screen programmatically using no hardcoded CGRect and the minimum number of constraints

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I have the following code in my ViewController

```
let imageView               = UIImageView()
imageView.backgroundColor   = UIColor.blueColor()
imageView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(120.0).active = true
imageView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(120.0).active = true
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "buttonFollowCheckGreen")

let textLabel               = UILabel()
textLabel.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(self.view.frame.width).active = true
textLabel.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(20.0).active = true
textLabel.text  = "Hi World"
textLabel.font = UIFont(name:kFontName, size:24)
textLabel.textAlignment = .Center

let stackView   = UIStackView()
stackView.axis  = UILayoutConstraintAxis.Vertical
// stackView.distribution  = UIStackViewDistribution.EqualSpacing
// stackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.Center
stackView.spacing   = 16.0

stackView.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
stackView.addArrangedSubview(textLabel)
stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

self.view.addSubview(stackView)

stackView.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.centerXAnchor).active = true
stackView.centerYAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.centerYAnchor).active = true
```

However, this renders as follows :
[image: actual]

I would like to have it render as follows :

[image: expected]

What is the minimum change to the above code to accomplish this. I was hoping for a property on the stackView that would align it to the top.

Comment: The last two lines in your code are centring your stack view in your view. You could start by changing that.

Comment: I have the same result even if I comment out the 2 lines you were referring to (Edited in original question also)

Comment: And what constraints did you replace them with?

Comment: I tried stackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.Leading and stackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.Top but that gives me the unexpected result of the blue rectangle floating to the left instead of to the top.

Comment: Thanks @Abizern I managed to get the blue rectangle aligned with the top by changing the last line to         stackView.centerYAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.topAnchor).active = true but I still need a margin-top between the stackview and the top of the frame. Please help if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the last two lines with:

```
stackView.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.centerXAnchor).active = true

let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
    item: stackView, 
    attribute: .Top, 
    relatedBy: .Equal, 
    toItem: topLayoutGuide, 
    attribute: .Bottom, 
    multiplier: 1.0, 
    constant: 0.0
)
view.addConstraint(constraint)
```

Also, your are creating views in code that you are using with auto layout, so you need to turn off the autoresizing mask by adding the following two lines

```
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
textLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

You've still got some conflicts with the views in your stack view, but that's not part of the question, so I'll leave that for you to try and fix.